# How to filter outer array records on the basis of inner array value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an object of array inside another object. So, there are two nested ng-repeat in my html. I am trying to hide the label data if ACTION is not "Changed"
for ex. in below example, last row "Changed L3" should not display.

**My scope data:**

```
 $scope.groups =
    [{
      "label": "L1",
      "tabledata": [{
                      "FIELDNAME": "C1 Entity",
                      "SCREEN": "A",
                      "ORIGINALVALUE": "NA",
                      "ACTION": "Changed",
                      "NEWVALUE": "Something",
                      "TYPEACT": "RB"

                   },
                   {
                          "FIELDNAME": "C2 Entity",
                          "SCREEN": "A",
                          "ORIGINALVALUE": "NA",
                          "ACTION": "Changed",
                          "NEWVALUE": "SSSS",
                          "TYPEACT": "RB"

                       }
                      ]

    },
    {
      "label": "L2",
      "tabledata": [{
                      "FIELDNAME": "B1 Entity",
                      "SCREEN": "B",
                      "ORIGINALVALUE": "NA",
                      "ACTION": "Changed",
                      "NEWVALUE": "Something",
                      "TYPEACT": "RB"

                   },
                   {
                      "FIELDNAME": "B2 Entity",
                      "SCREEN": "B",
                      "ORIGINALVALUE": "NA",
                      "ACTION": "Changed",
                      "NEWVALUE": "Something",
                      "TYPEACT": "RB"

                   }
                   ]

    },

     {
      "label": "L3",
      "tabledata": [{
                      "FIELDNAME": "A Entity",
                      "SCREEN": "C",
                      "ORIGINALVALUE": "NA",
                      "ACTION": "Added",
                      "NEWVALUE": "Something",
                      "TYPEACT": "RB"

                   }]

    }]
```

**My html**

```
<div ng-repeat="group in groups" >
        <p><b>{{ "Changed " + group.label }}</b>
                </p>
        <table class="table table-bordered" >
            <tbody >
                <tr >
                    <th width ="20%"><b ng-bind="column1" ></b></th>
                    <th width ="40%"><b>Previous value </b></th>
                    <th width ="40%"><b ng-bind="column3" ></b> </th>
                    <th width ="10%"><b>Action </b></th>
                </tr>
                <!-- BEGIN: Inner ngRepeat. -->
                <tr ng-repeat="endorsedata in group.tabledata | filter :{ACTION :  'Changed'}  | orderBy:'FIELDNAME' " >
                    <td ng-init ="showRow = 1">{{ endorsedata.FIELDNAME }}</td>
                    <td>{{ endorsedata.ORIGINALVALUE }}</td>
                    <td>{{ endorsedata.NEWVALUE }}</td>
                    <!-- <td>{{ endorsedata.ACTION }}</td> -->
                </tr>
                <!-- END: Inner ngRepeat. -->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I want to hide the labels if there is value other than 'Changed' in ACTION attribute. How can this achieved?

[Plunker Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OHcCZhfQqPVLWRUUqdmX?p=preview)

**EDIT:** Plunker Link updated.

Comment: Yeah that's not so difficult, if you create yourself a filter, then inside it for that property use `$filter` you can achieve this. Fairly straightforward. Look at `$filter` source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go then, this should do what you want: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x5C25WO2DzjLObi17xXl?p=preview)

Basically, created a filter with same overloads as the angular `$filter`. Then inside for each `tabledata` I use a filter option on it.

If the filtered array is different from the original array then we can safely say that a something was found. You can easily modify this to meet your exact needs.

The example shows how you can filter the top most array via the child array.